# Facebook SDK Login with Cordova + Reactjs "Can't load URL" on mobile devices

Tags: reactjs, cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to build hybrid mobile application by using Cordova + React.js and it has Facebook Login. So, I'm trying to use [cordova-plugin-facebook4](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-facebook4), [react-facebook-login](https://github.com/keppelen/react-facebook-login) and [Facebook javascript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web).

For Cordova plugin, it worked on web browser but when I tested on mobile device (iOS and Android) it not bring me to Facebook login page.

For react-facebook-login and Facebook JavaScript SDK, both worked on web browser but on mobile device, I got an error

> Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.

In the URL look like this

```
channel_url=https://staticxx.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter.php?version=45#cb=xxxxxx
domain=
fallback_redirect_uri=file:///Users/{username}/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/xxx/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/xxx/my.app/www/index.html#/
redirect_uri=https://staticxx.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter.php?version=45#cb=xxxxx
```

I've added localhost to app domain that I don't know which domain need to add to App Domains.

My code look like

```
 componentDidMount() {
    window.fbAsyncInit = () => {
      window.FB.init({
        appId: "xxxxxx",
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
        version: "v5.0"
      });

      window.FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
    };

    (function(d, s, id) {
      var js,
        fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) {
        return;
      }
      js = d.createElement(s);
      js.id = id;
      js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    })(document, "script", "facebook-jssdk");
  }



onFacebook = () => {
    window.FB.login(
      resp => {
        console.log(resp);
      },
      { scope: "public_profile,email" }
    );
  };
```

For login button

```
<div className="btn_full_width" onClick={this.onFacebook}>
     Continue with Facebook
</div>
```

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score -1):

You have to [allow an intent](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/#allow-intent) to those domains in your cordova `config.xml` or `config.template.xml`

```
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="file://*/*" />
```

Or make it more specified

`<allow-intent href="https://staticxx.facebook.com/*" />`

If possible, mind sharing part or all of your cordova config?